# How to print number of stars in output to the number of words in a sentence displayed?

Tags: javascript, split

I trying to count the number of words in a sentence and in output i want to display the same number of stars " * "

As a beginner working on improving logics in coding .  Where i am wrong in this code ?? Please help me out .. thanks in advance

```js
var s_string = "The world of beautiful stories";

var count = s_string.split(" ").length;

var spl = ' ';

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  spl = spl + (" * ");
}
console.log(spl); // expected output * * * * *
```

I expect the output from the displayed input `"The world of beautiful people"` to be like `* * * * *`.

Comment: `Console` should be lower case: `console.log()`

Comment: If you are already getting the correct output then this question might be more suitable in https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @karthick Where did he say that he's already getting the correct output? He asked what he's doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar yeah he didnt mention it but I got confused with "on improving logics in coding" and whatever he expected is already present except for the typo

Comment: When I run your code I get the expected output. Why do you think you have an error (other than the `Console` typo)?

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks a lot

Comment: @karthick i got the error . thx

Comment: @Barmar yes it was typo . my bad thanks

Comment: But... Your snippet is correct, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const countWordsWithStars = phrase =>{
    const wordsCount = phrase.split(' ').length
    let stars = ''
    for(let i=0; i < wordsCount; i++){
        stars += '*'
    }
   return stars
 }
```